# Publishing UML models in RSA 8.0

Tags: uml, rational-rsa

Do anyone found where is this feature?
I need to publish a lot of models to customers who doesn't have Rational Software Architect.

Answer (score 1):

RSA is using the GMF plugin which is graphical mapper to UML model. You need to generate a XMI export of your model.
You can not visualize RSA model if you don't have RSA software or a compatible tool like Omondo.

What could be done is to export the model and then open it with the Eclipse model Explorer which is a free open source plugin. You will not an UML editor but a kind of model browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Publish to Web" capability of RSA to publish information in models as HTML pages. This option is available under the top level "Modeling" Menu. Navigate to Modeling>Publish>Web.

Make sure that model you want to publish is selected.

Comment: There is not this option in RSA 8.0

Comment: yes, this option is there in 8.0. You have to be in the "Modeling" perspective for the option to show up in the application menu bar.

Comment: Manesh, I have RSA 8.0 here without this option. See in the picture: http://i.imgur.com/ylu21.png and the plugins of RSA 8 here: http://i.imgur.com/TpHRj.png

Comment: Not sure why you aren't seeing this option. In the online trial of RSA v8.0.3 http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/architect/tryonline.html, I see that the Web Publish option is there.

Comment: I suggest that you take your question to RSA user forum https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=430&start=0

Comment: yes.. I can remember I've installed full version and activate all plugins